# How to get the last URL fetched by cURL?

Tags: php, curl

If a given URL is redirected to another one, `cURL` will fetch the last one by

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

but how to record what was the last URL fetched by cURL?

With

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

we do not know what was the actuall url fetched by `cURL`, as `$link` has been redirected to the final location. How to record the last location in a string?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `curl_getinfo()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

```
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

Comment: Thanks, I had missed `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL`