# Find where URL redirects to using PHP

Tags: php, redirect, curl, file-get-contents

I am looking to find where a URL redirects to, currently I am getting a web page's information using file_get_contents() but some of the pages are returning a 301/302 header status and I want to use a function to find the url that the page redirects to;

```
function page_info($url) {
$fp = file_get_contents($url);
$title = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);
$h1 = preg_match("/<h1>(.*)<\/h1>/siU", $fp, $h1_matches);
$h2 = preg_match("/<h2>(.*)<\/h2>/siU", $fp, $h2_matches);
$meta_desc = get_meta_tags($url);
$data = array("title"=>trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1])), "metadesc" => $meta_desc['description'],"h1"=>trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $h1_matches[1])), "h2"=>trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $h2_matches[1])));
return $data;
}
```

Is there any way to just find out the url of the redirect so I can then run the page_info() function on the correct URL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the last URL fetched by cURL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637493/how-to-get-the-last-url-fetched-by-curl)

Comment: It isn't possible with `file_get_contents()`, AFAIK. Use cURL instead.

Comment: Parsing HTML with a regexp? [Yikes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Maybe there's a [better way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the php curl library. You can set it to follow redirects and then use the getinfo method to find our where it takes you.

```
$curl = curl_init('http://example.org/someredirect');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "foo");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_exec($curl);

if(!curl_errno($curl))
{
     $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
}
```

You can pass second parameters to the curl_getinfo method to get more specific information