# How to get the full URL from an rstyle link in php

Tags: php, redirect, hyperlink

I have a link: http://rstyle.me/n/bfj42hqgww

which redirects to https://www.missguided.co.uk/clothing/coats-jackets/double-breasted-tailored-long-faux-wool-coat-camel

How do I get the redirect link?

I tried the following:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Must be set to true so that PHP follows any "Location:" header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch); // $a will contain all headers
$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); // This is what you need, it will return you the last effective URL
echo $url;
```

but it did not work. I also tried:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); // We'll parse redirect url from header.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE); // We want to just get redirect url but not to follow it.
$response = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $response, $matches);
curl_close($ch);
echo !empty($matches[1]) ? trim($matches[1][0]) : 'No redirect found';
```

Comment: I did not test it but this seems to get the last url of cURL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637493/how-to-get-the-last-url-fetched-by-curl

Answer (score 0):

i don't have any knowledge about this but i am using in my website something like this for sending sms. so, you could try if it is workout.

```
$URL="example.com";  
$ch = curl_init($URL);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
$output = curl_exec($ch);      
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You got redirect not from server but from javascript. cURL doesn't execute javascript. When I open your link I saw that real link is hidden in a "title" tag.

```
$url = 'http://rstyle.me/n/bfj42hqgww';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Get real URL.
preg_match("|<title>(.+?)</title>|si", $data, $matches);

$link = ( isset($matches[1]) ) ? $matches[1] : '';

echo $link;
```

Comment: The link that it is returning in the title tag is https://www.missguided.co.uk/clothing/category/coats-jackets/double-breasted-tailored-long-faux-wool 

but which is not the actual link when i visit the short link

Comment: Also, instead of getting from the title tag is it possible to actually execute the javascript and get url of the target page because for another link of same domain the title tag does not have the link